# The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources

Tags: rest-api, magento2.4.4

I have installed `magento2.4.4` and `php8.1` and when trying to access rest api using bearer token it is giving error for all the routes.

```
 {
    "message": "The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.",
    "parameters": {
        "resources": "Magento_Catalog::products"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the full API call please?

Comment: its for all routes

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In `magento2.4.4` we have to make configuration like this to work rest api with integration token

[image: Congiuration Image]

Comment: This is only valid for integration tokens, not for bearer tokens that are created via the admin user.

Comment: mahn..i have been digging this all through..thanks for the help

Comment: @torhoehn but it does work for admin generated token too

Comment: Hello. I don't even have that select box in my dashboard. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for above solutions. I also encountered this smiliar issue after upgrade magento from 2.4.1 to 2.4.4-p2.
My customized rest API can not work and get the same error.
[image]

I debug the codes and found there is a configuration to control this logic. I set the "***Allow OAuth Access Tokens to be used as standalone Bearer tokens***" to be ***Yes*** and it works.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information, i faced the same issue and i have updated the configuration which you mentioned above it works for me!

Answer (score 1):

Is the token still valid? Maybe it is expired, in that case you should call

```
{{host}}/rest/V1/integration/admin/token
```

to get a new one. Then you can use it as the authentication token.
If the above call for example give you this as reponse

```
"z2hmps0r5bp72r1y8rvx7d25wy1odrcu"
```

In your further calls you must add a header like this

```
Authorization: Bearer z2hmps0r5bp72r1y8rvx7d25wy1odrcu
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: what could be the issue when it is not working from integration token?

Comment: have you tried to call different REST or use a different user? Can you try with an admin user?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. My bet is that there is something wrong whit the APi user profile. First let's go to your admin panel and check wich role is assigned to your API User in Settings => Permissions => All Users.

Now lets go to Settings => Permissions => user roles and check wich resources are accessible by the user

[image]

If this solved your issue please don't forget to upvote/ mark as answered.

Comment: All settings seems OK